# HxCPP Add Include Paths and Linker Options

Tags: configuration, haxe, ffi, cflags, hxcpp

I'm trying to use an external C++ library in Haxe. I have an `extern class` with an `@:include` meta, but I can't figure out how to add the directory containing some headers to the HxCPP include path, or add linker options to add to the lbrary path and link with the libraries. I assume it will involve using `@:buildXml`, and I have this:

```
@:buildXml("
<target id=\"default\">
    <cppflag value=\"-I...\" />
    <flag value=\"-L...\" />
    <lib base="..." />
</target>
")
```

, but those flags don't show up in the logged `g++` command. I can't find any documentation about adding include paths, or any real examples of build XML.

Comment: have you found? I have the same problem

Comment: @the_yellow_logo I tried looking at the sources of some other Haxe libraries with native code, but no luck.

Comment: https://matttuttle.com/2015/07/hxcpp-build-xml/ check this out, the missing doc for build.xml ;)